# Slave hdd error bios recognizes

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I recently encountered a slave hdd error after windows completely locked up and had to hold the power button to turn off my machine.

Since then, i have been presented with a

"2nd slave disk error" then promptly followed by a message to reboot.

I boot into BIOS to see my hard drive recognized but with zero size. Every search ive currently performed has shown solutions/discussed issues with the drive not being recognized in the bios? Or other solutions show steps from within windows on another HDD?

Im honestly at a loss and can't fully grasp/adapt whats being spoken about on the search results. Im almost at the point of just marking the drive as faulty with a viking funeral, but i thought to try here.

> 750gb drive ST3750630AS

I have attempted to boot into linux through a live CD and mounting the drive to no avail. I am unable to test the drive in another machine nor burn off any smart monitoring tools.

Prior to this, the drive had no issues nor shown signs of failing (stuck heads/dreaded clicking, lock ups, failing to boot/spin). Im honestly at a loss on how to proceed further. Let alone access the drive to back up files to an external drive (which is recognised by the live CD)

Comment: Does your HDD cannot be recognized in BIOS ever when all another HDDs detached? PS. ST3750630AS is Seagate, not Western Digital...

Comment: @Akina that is something i forgot to add in. The only other device present is a Sata disk drive. Even when removing. Same error/situation happens. The external drive is only plugged in and connected as of when it is needed

Comment: Replacing SATA cable, attaching to another port?

Comment: @akina correct. Same problem, even in post "auto detecting sata . . . Ide hard disk" then cuts over to 4th slave drive error with the new port

Comment: And can confirm i can hear the drive spinning up

Comment: Looks like on [this photo](https://dicom.spb.ru/images/articles/vostanovlenie-dannyh/recovery-seagate2.jpg)? If so, main possible reason (I think) is HDD service tables damage. If so, there is no programatical solution. Special recovering equipment (like PC-3000) needed. I'd recommend to contact to special DR-firm. !! Avoid of HDD firmware update !!

Comment: @akina exactly like that. With your opinion the drive is dead with no home remedy?

Comment: Have you tried putting the drive into a USB dock? I think sadly the truth is that the drive is dead.

Comment: @duck_tape_coder unfortunately, i do not have a USB dock. However, rummaging around a storage cupboard  i have found a older hard drive which looks to be running windows. If i can get this to successfully boot. How does the third party recovery software fetch up? Would it have any positive results?

Comment: *With your opinion the drive is dead with no home remedy?* If you do not have special recovering equipment mentioned above (plus software), that's absolutely right.